# Python delimiter in the sentence

Tags: python, csv, delimiter

I have the following code:

```
with open('comment.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    for row in readCSV:
```

What will happen is that: it will use "," for parsing the csv. But everything will be screwed if there are extra "," in a column named "content".

Is there a smart way to omit the "," in the column for normal parsing?

Thanks,

Comment: Does your column at least have double quotes?

Comment: If the dupe doesn't answer your question, please edit your question with a [mcve], so it is easy to reproduce your problem. Show your data and your efforts.